# Coger ID de cada registro de una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

estoy intentando obtener el id de cada una de las recetas que tengo guardadas en mi base de datos, pero tengo un problema y es que muestro por pantalla los registros en un bucle, entonces salen todas las recetas igual excepto que cambia el nombre, muestro el código a continuación:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT nombre_receta from receta";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <a href="#" class="border border-mandarina rounded-s shadow-xs">
        <i class="fa fa-duotone fa-drumstick-bite"></i>
        <?php echo $mostrar['nombre_receta'] ?>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu query claramente muestra que únicamente se esta haciendo la selección de la columna `nombre_receta` de la tabla `receta`. Debido a que no adjuntas la estructura de tu tabla `receta` es imposible saber cual es el nombre de la columna que representa al ID.

Por lo tanto, debes cambiar tu query para que sea de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_receta, nombre_receta from receta";
```

En este caso use `id_receta` como el nombre de la columna, Queda en ti usar el nombre correcto.

Posteriormente y donde lo necesites podrás obtener el ID de la misma forma que obtienes el nombre.

```
<?php echo $mostrar['receta_id'] ?> - <?php echo $mostrar['nombre_receta'] ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió mucho.